# What is the URI that points to the voting stats?

Tags: support

The last question I read in Meta-SF piqued my ..What is the URI to get the voting stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For previous elections you can see the stats at

- First Election:  https://serverfault.com/election/1
- Second Election: https://serverfault.com/election/2

The current election doesn't display stats at the moment so Shog9 will be working off figures that are not widely published at this time.

You can figure out how many people have voted in this election by looking at the number of people with a [constituent badge](https://serverfault.com/badges/198/constituent) and subtracting 515 which was the number that had been awarded prior to this election.

Comment: Also of note, http://serverfault.com/election/0 - or any other invalid election ID - will give you the winners (and stats summaries) of all prior elections.  Not sure if that's intentional or not, but it's useful :-)